# Don't know how to implement pointer to array of pointers to char

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm not great with pointers.  I know enough to get an array of pointers to char to work, as in the first example below.  But I don't want to pass an entire array of pointers, because it takes up too much room on the stack.  What I would like to do is pass a single pointer to the memory allocated for the array of pointers.  I have no idea how to do this.

This program works:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "$StdHdr.h"
#include "TmpTstPtr1.h"

#define SRC_LIN_SIZ 150

int main(int ArgCnt, char * ArgVal[])
{
    char        InpFilPth[MAX_PATH + 1];
    FILE        * InpFilPtr;
    char        ** SrcArr;
    unsigned    Sub1;
    unsigned    SrcArrCnt = 0;

    strncpy_s(InpFilPth, "TmpTstPtr1.cpp", strlen("TmpTstPtr1.cpp"));
    fopen_s(&InpFilPtr, InpFilPth, "r");
    SrcArr = (char **)malloc(999999 * sizeof(char *));
    LodSrcArr(InpFilPtr, SrcArr, &SrcArrCnt);
    for (Sub1 = 0; Sub1 < SrcArrCnt; Sub1++) {
        printf("SrcArr[%d] = %s\n", Sub1, SrcArr[Sub1]);
    }
    fclose(InpFilPtr);

    return 0;
}

void LodSrcArr(FILE * InpFilPtr, char ** SrcArr, unsigned * SrcArrCnt)
{
    char        SrcLin[SRC_LIN_SIZ + 1];
    char        * GetStrPtr;


    GetStrPtr = GetStr(SrcLin, SRC_LIN_SIZ, InpFilPtr);
    while (GetStrPtr != NULL) {
        SrcArr[*SrcArrCnt] = (char *)malloc(SRC_LIN_SIZ + 1);
        //      CpySiz(SrcArr[*SrcArrCnt], strlen(SrcLin) + 1, SrcLin);
        errno = strncpy_s(SrcArr[*SrcArrCnt], SRC_LIN_SIZ + 1, SrcLin, strlen(SrcLin));
        (*SrcArrCnt)++;
        GetStrPtr = GetStr(SrcLin, SRC_LIN_SIZ, InpFilPtr);
    }
}


char * GetStr(char * Str, const int MaxChr, FILE * InpFilPtr)
{
    char        * InpRtnVal = NULL;
    unsigned    Sub1;

    //  Get string from input file.  Find the end of the string if something entered.
    InpRtnVal = fgets(Str, MaxChr + 1, InpFilPtr);
    if (InpRtnVal != NULL) {
        Sub1 = 0;
        while (Str[Sub1] != '\n' && Str[Sub1] != '\0') {
            Sub1++;
        }
        //  Replace newline with null.
        if (Str[Sub1] == '\n') {
            Str[Sub1] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return InpRtnVal;
```

The following program doesn't even come close:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "$StdHdr.h"
#include "TmpTstPtr2.h"

#define SRC_LIN_SIZ 150

int main(int ArgCnt, char * ArgVal[])
{
    char        InpFilPth[MAX_PATH + 1];
    FILE        * InpFilPtr;
    char        ** SrcArr;
    unsigned    Sub1;
    unsigned    SrcArrCnt = 0;
    char        *** SrcArrPtr = NULL;

    strncpy_s(InpFilPth, "TmpTstPtr2.cpp", strlen("TmpTstPtr2.cpp"));
    fopen_s(&InpFilPtr, InpFilPth, "r");
    SrcArr = (char **)malloc(999999 * sizeof(char *));
    SrcArrPtr = &SrcArr;
    LodSrcArr(InpFilPtr, SrcArrPtr, &SrcArrCnt);
    SrcArrPtr = &SrcArr;
    for (Sub1 = 0; Sub1 < SrcArrCnt; Sub1++) {
//      printf("SrcArr[%d] = %s\n", Sub1, SrcArr[Sub1]);    // got "Exception thrown: read access violation. it was 0xCDCDCDCD."
        printf("SrcArr[%d] = %s\n", Sub1, **SrcArrPtr);     // get 75 lines of garbage
        (**SrcArrPtr) += sizeof(char *);
    }
    fclose(InpFilPtr);

    return 0;
}


void LodSrcArr(FILE * InpFilPtr, char *** SrcArrPtr, unsigned * SrcArrCnt)
{
    char        SrcLin[SRC_LIN_SIZ + 1];
    char        * GetStrPtr;


    GetStrPtr = GetStr(SrcLin, SRC_LIN_SIZ, InpFilPtr);
    //  while (GetStrPtr != NULL and *SrcArrCnt == 0) {
    while (GetStrPtr != NULL) {
        **SrcArrPtr = (char *)malloc(SRC_LIN_SIZ + 1);
        //      CpySiz(SrcArr[*SrcArrCnt], strlen(SrcLin) + 1, SrcLin);
        errno = strncpy_s(**SrcArrPtr, SRC_LIN_SIZ + 1, SrcLin, strlen(SrcLin));
        (**SrcArrPtr) += sizeof(char *);
        (*SrcArrCnt)++;
        GetStrPtr = GetStr(SrcLin, SRC_LIN_SIZ, InpFilPtr);
    }
}


char * GetStr(char * Str, const int MaxChr, FILE * InpFilPtr)
{
    char        * InpRtnVal = NULL;
    unsigned    Sub1;

    //  Get string from input file.  Find the end of the string if something entered.
    InpRtnVal = fgets(Str, MaxChr + 1, InpFilPtr);
    if (InpRtnVal != NULL) {
        Sub1 = 0;
        while (Str[Sub1] != '\n' && Str[Sub1] != '\0') {
            Sub1++;
        }
        //  Replace newline with null.
        if (Str[Sub1] == '\n') {
            Str[Sub1] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return InpRtnVal;
}
```

As the comments say, when I try to access `SrcArr` via a subscript, I get a run-time error.  When I try to access via the pointer, I get garbage.  The problem may be where I say `SrcArrPtr = &SrcArr;`.  I don't know if it's significant, but the garbage printed is 4 characters shorter with each subsequent line.  As if it's actually printing the array of pointers itself, rather than the strings they point to.  I dunno.

The reason I coded it as above is in order to get the program to compile.  I've never tried to use 3 pointers before.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  If so, can someone show me how?  An explanation of how it works would be nice, but not necessary.  (I'm using Visual Studio 2017, though I don't think it matters.)

TIA.

Comment: You tagged your question with two distinct languages: C++ and C. Which is it?

Comment: Arrays do not get copied when passed to a function - when you pass an array expression to a function, the expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element.  And is this supposed to be C or C++?

Comment: Thx for the question.  The program is a .cpp, which is the MS default.  But the code is actually just standard C.

Comment: .cpp is for C++ code. If that's the default extension there is a great chance your project is set to C++ and will be compiled using a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. It's important to know which language you're actually using to properly help you.

Comment: C++ is not C. For C++ the answer is "you are doing it all wrong, forget everything you know and start over". For C, the answer is "don't be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Thx for changing the tag to just be C.  Will try to recompile using the C compiler.

Comment: I have to agree with you, n.m.  I don't want to use 3 stars, but I just want to be able to pass a single pointer to an array of pointers to char.  Is this even possible?

Comment: @J.Toran Just rename your source file to `*.c` and `cl` will compile them in C mode. You are using `strncpy_s()` inclorrectly, please RTFM.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a pointer to an array?

Comment: @Swordfish,  I did as you said and found that the C compiler works a little differently than the C++ compiler on the strncpy_s.  So I added a sizeof(InpFilPth) and it compiled okay.  However the results were the same.

Comment: @n.m.  I don't actually need to pass a pointer to the array.  I just wanted to do it that way so I didn't have to take up all the space on the stack that would be needed to pass the entire array of pointers.  Would rather just pass a single pointer.

Comment: @J.Toran An Array will \*never\* be passed by value! Also `strncpy_s()` is the same function that doesn't care if it is called by C++- or C-code. When your compiler didn't warn you when compiling as C++-code your warning level setting is too low. Wrong is wrong.

Comment: You could not "pass an entire array" even if you wanted to. C arrays don't work this way. You always pass a pointer to the first element of the array. Please learn about *array-to-pointer decay*. In your case however you don't need to pass an array in any shape or form. You need to *return an array*.

Comment: Thx for all the replies.  Excuse my ignorance, n.m.  Are you saying that only the space of one pointer is used up on the stack?  If so, then I don't need to worry about the space taken up by 999,999 pointers, right?

Comment: @J.Toran Y e s !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char* bar[10]) { // a real array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        bar[i] = calloc(2, 1);
        bar[i][0] = '0' + i;
    }
}

void xox(char **qux) { // pointer to some char-pointers on the heap
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        qux[i] = calloc(2, 1);
        qux[i][0] = '0' + i;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char* bar[10]; // a "real" array
    foo(bar);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        puts(bar[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    // cleanup:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        free(bar[i]);

    // plan b:
    char **qux = calloc(10, sizeof(*qux));
    xox(qux);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        puts(qux[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    // cleanup:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        free(qux[i]);
    free(qux);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, Swordfish.  I'm trying to figure out if you're passing the entire array of pointers, or not.  Thx again.

Comment: A single pointer is passed both times. There is no way to pass "a whole array" to a function. Not in C and not in C++. It is also not possible to return an array from a function, only pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is pass a single pointer to the memory
>   allocated for the array of pointers.

Suppose you have some integers on the heap, like this:

```
int *integers = (int*)malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```

And now suppose you have some pointers, also on the heap:

```
int **pointers = (int**)malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
```

Now let's assign the pointers to the addresses of the integers:

```
pointers[0] = &integers[0];
pointers[1] = &integers[1];
pointers[2] = &integers[2];
pointers[3] = &integers[3];
```

In this example, `pointers` is a pointer to an array of pointers (on the heap) pointing to some integers (also on the heap). You can freely pass `pointers` around and use it in another function.

Or, if you wanted the array of pointer to be on the stack:

```
int* pointers[4];
pointers[0] = &integers[0];
pointers[1] = &integers[1];
pointers[2] = &integers[2];
pointers[3] = &integers[3];
int **ppointer = pointers;
```

Now `ppointer` is also a pointer pointing to an array of pointers that point to some integers on the heap. Just notice that this time, those pointers are on the stack, not on the heap. So if you return from this function, they're out of scope and you may not access them anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Swordfish. All those arrays, pointers, heap and stack got me confused for a second.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Blaze, and the edit Swordfish.

Answer (score 0):

You're operating under a misconception.  Neither C nor C++ pass a copy of an array to a function, nor can they return an array from a function.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.

Thus, if you declare an array like

```
char *ptrs[N];
```

and pass it to a function as

```
foo( ptrs );
```

the *expression* `ptrs` is implicitly converted from "N-element array of `char *`" to "pointer to `char *`", and what `foo` actually receives is a pointer to the first element of the array - it's effectively the same as writing

```
foo( &ptrs[0] );
```

The prototype can be written as either

```
void foo( char **ptrs )
```

or

```
void foo( char *ptrs[] )
```

or

```
void foo( char *ptrs[N] )
```

In a function parameter declaration, array declarators are "adjusted" to be pointer declarators - IOW, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both interpreted to mean `T *a`.  This is *only* true in a function parameter declaration, though.

As a matter of style...

In C, the cast on `malloc` is unnecessary<sup>1</sup>, and under C89 it can suppress a useful diagnostic if you forget to include `stdlib.h` or otherwise don't have a declaration for `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`) in scope.  Under C99 and later, you'll get a diagnostic for not having a declaration, but C89 still allowed implicit `int` declarations, and the cast will prevent the compiler from yelling at you because `int` and pointer types are not compatible.  I bring this up because MS's support for C past C89 is a bit spotty.

To minimize your maintenance burden, it's better to avoid explicitly naming types in a `malloc` call.  You can rewrite

```
SrcArr = (char **)malloc(999999 * sizeof(char *));
```

as

```
SrcArr = malloc( 999999 * sizeof *SrcArr ); // you sure you need that many elements??!
```

Since `SrcArr` has type `char **`, the *expression* `*SrcArr` has type `char *`, so `sizeof *SrcArr` is the same as `sizeof (char **)`.  In general, a `malloc` call can be written

```
T *p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );
```

The same is true for `calloc` and `realloc`.

---

1. This is not the cast in C++, since C++ doesn't allow implicit conversion from `void *` to other pointer types, but if you're writing C++ you shouldn't be using `malloc` *anyway*.